# How can I implement the length function for S4 classes?

Tags: r, r-s4

I want to implement the `length()` function in R for S4 class instances. I would have a class:

```
setClass("A", slots = c(ll = "list"))
```

Then, I want to create an instance `inst` of class A and call `length(inst)`.

My previous attempts have failed and so far I could only find a way to do this for S3 classes. (Like the `Formula` package does [here](https://github.com/cran/Formula/blob/master/R/Formula.R).)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you just want your `length()` method to delegate to the slot "ll".

```
setMethod("length", signature = "A", definition = function(x) length(x@ll))
```

Comment: Thank you, I could have sworn this did not work for me when I tried it... but it works!